# Is $K\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomorphic to an interval if $K$ is connected but $K\setminus\{x\}$ is not for any $x\in K$? Must it have empty interior?

Tags: general-topology

> Given that $K$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\forall x\in K, K\setminus\{x\}$ is not connected, then
>
> 1. K must be homeomorphic to an interval of $\mathbb{R}$
> 2. K must have empty interior.

Well, I feel that 1 is correct but I'm not able to make it formal, and I'm not sure about 2.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Is $K$ connected?

Comment: 2. is correct: removing a point of interior does not disconnect a set, because a disk minus a point is still connected.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev You are assuming that $K$ is connected. If a set is not connected, it is possible that removing a point from the interior of the set keeps the set disconnected.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev Nevermind, the post has been edited to say that $K$ is connected.

Comment: 1 is false: take the union of two axes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copying & expanding comments:

1 is false: take the union of two axes. You can find a topological characterization of intervals in *Analytic Topology* by Whyburn.

2 is correct: removing a point of interior does not disconnect a set, because a disk minus a point is still connected.